# Выбрать из масива найбольшую сумму 4 чисел

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм

Пример:
Есть масив {100, 123, 134,140, 123, 124,100, 1233, 134}. Нужно найти максимальную сумму из четырех чисел, но чтобы она не превышала 500.

Comment: Вам просто код дать?

Comment: Ну попробуйте перебором...

Answer (score 1):

То, что вы хотите сделать, называется ["задача о рюкзаке"](https://vscode.ru/prog-lessons/zadacha-o-ryukzake.html). Только вам ещё проще, у вас не объекты в массиве, а обычные числа.

Судя по метке, вам нужен алгоритм решения. Алгоритм решения этой задачи я привёл выше по ссылке.